# Is there a way to use MSAL or any Azure API to login a user without interaction when the user is using MFA?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal

I need to log into an account that has MFA (Multi Factor Authentication) enabled to be able to retrieve an access token.

This is alright if I use MSAL with interactive Login into a registered app in Azure. But I want to automate the process so it can run inside an Azure Function.

The problem arises when I try to login using Password. The code fails, saying the login requires interaction.

Dropping the MFA is an unwanted action.

I was hoping that someone who has experienced similar issue could direct me into an answer that would allow me to keep MFA and login into the account without requiring interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can't skip MFA.
One way that you can achieve something like this is to do an interactive login, store the received refresh token, and then use that to acquire tokens when needed.
You may need to repeat the interactive authentication if the refresh token stops working.